# How to pass specs to gcc linker?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I need to specify a pre-configured specs file to *arm-none-eabi-gcc* toolchain to enable semihosting. The usual way is to use *--specs* argument for gcc, but in my build system the build phase is separate from linking phase. First the object files are built, and then *arm-none-eabi-ld* is called to generate "executable" *AXF* image.

How do I pass specs file argument to linker?

BTW here's the relevant part of arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain documentation:

> Please be noticed that --specs=nano.specs is a linker option. Be sure
>   to include in linker option if compiling and linking are separated.

Comment: `-Xlinker --specs=nano.specs`?

Comment: The -Xlinker is argument for gcc executable. I want argument for ld executable which would tell linker to use specs file definitions (if that's even possible).

Comment: OK, I rewrote linking step to use gcc instead of ld (using -Xlinker to set linking options) and it seems to work. I would still like to know if it's possible to use ld executable and still apply specs file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I pass specs file argument to linker?

None of the linkers accept `specs` files -- it's a GCC (compiler driver) feature.

So no, you can't.